# how to transfer domain to weebly when tucows hides whois

Tags: domains, weebly

Trying to transfer a domain from ipower (which uses tucows for registrar) to weebly.

Unlocked the domain, no privacy is set, but ipower says that due to gdpr the whois data will not be made public.

Weebly says they can't do the transfer without whois being public.

So, pretty much screwed, site unavailable in the meantime.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Due to GDPR there is no more or less and less public data, and ICANN FOAs (I imagine you are talking about gTLD domain names, you do not say) are not possible anymore so registrars adapt to that and other registrars are able to handle that. If weebly is not a registrar itself you may try using another one. But "site unavailable in the meantime" makes no sense, DNS resolution is orthogonal to registrar transfers. You may need to explain your problem more.

Comment: Thanks, site unavailable may well be unrelated, so have asked current host to look into that.


Weebly tech support said 
"...Unfortunately at this time we are not able to transfer domains into Weebly. This is due to the recent changes to domain privacy laws that were passed that make it impossible for us to verify the admin email. We are working to get this resolved as quickly as possible, but as of right now, it is an issue that affects all transfers, not just to or from Weebly..."


So they are intimating that this is an issue everywhere?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: You repeat the same points but there are still not enough details (what domain, what current provider, why unavailable now, what happened before, why are you speaking about a transfer now, etc...) to understand your case and help you.

Comment: I stated in first sentence that it is a transfer FROM ipower (tucows) TO weebly.
The site is working now (still on ipower), but weebly still can't do the transfer.
I don't see why the exact site would matter to you, but it is hoedownlandscaping.com

Comment: Yes the name helps. Your website is available, so your problem is not clear. What does "site unavailable" means for you. Note however that you are 2 days before expiration which has two consequences : do not attempt to transfer it now, it is far too late anyway and if you do not renew it "quickly" your registrar may stop making it available on Internet. So, first renew it at your current registrar, wait at least 2 months (for reasons too long to explain in a comment) and then try a transfer. If weebly still can not do it then, you will need to shop elsewhere.

Comment: *Registry Expiry Date: 2018-07-13T04:51:05Z*

Comment: Thanks, Patrick.  I renewed it, so will see if weebly can get the transfer figured out, but at least the site is up in the meantime.

Comment: Wait at least 2 months before starting the transfer. Otherwise, due to some complex rules you may loose time and money: renewal adds 1 year, and transfer too, but if you do the transfer too short after the renewal, then the renewal get canceled and the end result is that your domain will have only 1 year more as expiration where you will have paid for 2 (one for the renewal at previous registrar, one for transfer at new registrar). You surely got emails from registrar telling you expiration is near and the consequences... if not, make sure your email addresses are correct.